# How to get autostart permission?

Tags: android, permissions, autostart

For the application I write crash stability is quite important. I found that if app doesn't have autostart permission it does not receive properly `onTaskRemoved` callback in `Service` . At least this happens on my Xiaomi smartphone. When I turn this permission on manually callback started to be called.

But!! while I turned this permission on manually I found that there are applications that received this permission without help. I.e. Facebook, AliExpress, Moovit etc.

How did they received this permission? I tried to receive `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`. This doesn't help. What is the trick?

Comment: I am not sure but unfortunately this could not be possible I had also that problem. I solved this by showing user a Dialogue Box for on AutoStart manually as Twilight or other application does

Comment: Moovit and Viber do not look like apps that Xiaomi care specially for. that's  why I suppose that it's possible.